# URLSession HTTP Error not updating back in view unless the action is initiated again

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with a button that calls an API, the API either returns an HTTP code 200 or 400 based on a particular scenario.

The button works just fine and everything works smoothly if code 200 is returned, however if code 400 is returned, the view is not updated that the user have to click on the button once again to get the updated message.

I added the http code property as a published variable in the VM's class and the http is an observable, but it doesn't get updated in the view on the first API call, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I made a lot of changes to the shared code just to help in demonstrating the actual problem.

Update: Also I think another part of the problem, is that the url function returns the value before the url session returns the data, I don't know why this is happening, that when I execute it a second time it uses the values from the previous execution.

```
HTTPError Class
```

```
class HTTPError : Codable, ObservableObject {
var statusCode: Int?
var message: [String]?
var error: String?

init(statusCode: Int? = nil, message: [String]? = [], error: String? = nil){
    self.statusCode = statusCode
    self.message = message ?? []
    self.error = error
}

convenience required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.statusCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .statusCode)
    do {
        self.message = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .message)
    } catch {
        guard let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: 
        .message) else {return}
        self.message = []
        self.message?.append(value)
    }
    self.error = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error)
}
```

```
VM Class
```

```
class VM: ObservableObject {
@Published var isLoading = true
@Published var httpError = HTTPError()

 func checkDriverIn(_ record: DriverQRParam) async -> (Bool) {
    ...
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    ...
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do {
        ...
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, 
            error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            self.httpError = try! JSONDecoder().decode(HTTPError.self, from: data)
            //gets updated just fine in this class//
        }
        task.resume()
    }catch {
        print("Couldn't encode data \(String(describing: error))")
    }
    
    if httpError.statusCode != nil && httpError.statusCode == 400 {
        return (false)
    } else {
        return (true)
    }
}
```

```
View.Swift
```

```
 struct xyz: View {

 @State private var VM = VM()

 Button("click") {
 Task {
 await VM.checkDriverIn(driverParam)
 }
}

}
```

Comment: Use StateObject for ObservableObjects — not State

Comment: Your HTTPError should be a struct — not a class or ObservableObject

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you, if you want to answer the question go ahead and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just FYI you are mixing closures and async await, they are incompatible and not working as you expect without a Continuation. You should watch “Meet async await”